# PXE booting via a trunk port?

Tags: linux, vlan, pxe-boot, kickstart

is is possible to pxe boot (a la as the first step in a cobbler install) when a system is hooked into a spanned switch port?

I guess my question is can the pxe process somehow be made aware of vlan tags coming in and use one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason to not have the default VLAN be the one you PXE boot from?

If so, some systems (e.g. IBM UEFI-based systems) can handle PXE booting from a VLAN.